# Fine-grained adjustment of wedge text in pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, pie-chart

I have a pie chart with three wedges. I'm displaying the percent values for each wedge in the wedge itself using the `autopct` setting. One of the wedges is quite small, and the wedge's inner text overlaps with the wedge's margins which doesn't look very nice.

I would like to move the inner text from the center of the wedge to the outer edge of the wedge because there is more space for the text. But the text should still be completely inside the wedge. This is possible for the inner texts of all wedges at the same time by adjusting the `pctdistance` value. However, I would like to do it for one wedge only.

Can I adjust the position of a single wedge's inner text relative to the wedge instead of having to specify absolute coordinates using [`Text.set_position`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_position)?

Comment: I suspect you are going to have to grab the location wedge and do the math your self.

Comment: @tcaswell Well, that's actually something I want to avoid. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Yes` is a default answer on any question regarding matplotlib library from my experience. ))

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# set chart style
plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery-nogrid')

# set data
x = [0.1, 2, 3, 4]

# set colors of segments
colors = plt.get_cmap('GnBu')(np.linspace(0.2, 0.7, len(x)))

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
w,l,p = ax.pie(x, colors=colors, radius=3, wedgeprops={"linewidth": 1, "edgecolor": "white"}, 
               frame=False, startangle=0, autopct='%.1f%%', pctdistance=1)

# set required distance per segment from chart center
pctdists = [.92, .3, .3, .3]

for t, d in zip(p, pctdists):
    xi, yi = t.get_position()
    ri = np.sqrt(xi**2+yi**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(yi,xi)
    x = d*ri*np.cos(phi)
    y = d*ri*np.sin(phi)
    t.set_position((x,y))

plt.show()
```

Returns

[image]